# Using X.509 Certificate with UserName clientCredentialType

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, x509certificate

I am creating a WCF service that requires a proxy username and password, in order to do this I need to provide a Service Certificate for which I have supplied our company Verisign Certificate which is valid.

The problem I am having is whenever I use the following configuration I get a error message "The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials."

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WSBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="devstage1.vcg-online.net" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPublisher" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Acre.IntegrationService.CustomValidator, Acre.IntegrationService" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Acre.IntegrationService.IntegrationService" behaviorConfiguration="WSBehaviour">

    <endpoint address="http://localhost/Acre.IntegrationService/IntegrationService.svc"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="WSBinding"
              contract="Acre.IntegrationService.IIntegrationService"
              name="WS" />

    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSBinding" allowCookies="false">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

UPDATED CONFIG

I have installed the certificate in the console using mmc.exe to the following paths

Certificates(Local Computer)/Personal/Certificates/
Certificates(Local Computer)/Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates/
Certificates(Local Computer)/Trusted Publishers/Certificates/

I have searched the interweb and can not find a clear solution to my problem.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Note: The certificate is also installed in those location under current user as well as computer. And has been imported into IIS

Comment: You should specify a serviceCertificate that needs to be used. Are you trying to secure the service with SSL over the transport channel?

Comment: I am specifying a Certificate in the Service behaviour, and yes SSL over transport for the custom authorisation... ignore that, I have just noticed I am using a client certificate, I will change that and try it

Comment: I changed the config to have a serviceCertificate and now the error is KeySet does not exist

Comment: Is it a self signed certificate? Also please do update your config

Comment: Update done, no it is not self sign, it was provided to us by Verisign

Comment: Have you installed the service certificate in Trusted Publisher store. I guess it needs to be on Local Computer --> Personal folder. Also if you are using ssl then your mex endpoint needs to be mexHttpsBinding and your httpGetEnabled should be false with httpsGetEnabled True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue, @Rajesh you were correct with the clientCertificate needing to be serverCertificate, that corrected the error with not finding the certificate, thanks for that. The certificate was already installed on the machine for computer user.

The problem with the key set was the certificate did not have the correct account permission set to it. I changed the permisisons to allow the IIS_USRS to have access to the certificate and now it is fixed